# $.plot is not a function Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, plot, charts

I tried to add a chart to my webpage.
But after fixing a few errors I still can't get it to work.
The only error I get is `$.plot` is not a function..

I hope that someone can help me out?

The wegpage is: http://linuxproject.be/index2.html
Login: blank
pass: projectuc

You can see my chart at the bottom of the page at
http://linuxproject.be/index2.html .

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flot-graphs/Hif0-Ddopvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js fixed the problem.

Solved